# What's the penalty exp on past lives while leveling a different life?

Tags: fantasy-life

In Fantasy Life your job is referred to as your Life. You can swap between them at will by visiting the guild master and asking to change but he mentions that your skills from past lives will not level as fast as they would if they were your current life. How much slower is what I am wondering as there are some jobs I would like to have access to the skills but may not really need to level them up at a faster rate.

Comment: I think I will try to test this tonight. Hopefully it's mostly universal. Just change through the crafting jobs and see how much exp you get for different recipes. (I hope Smithing isn't .75 while a carpenter but .25 while a Mercenary)

Comment: So far it looks like it's 80% exp as other Jobs. But unfortunately my first test I made a "good" pickaxe and the other Lives I just made normal ones.

Comment: I am confused as to why you have to use different tools? When I became a blacksmith and carpenter I immediately made all tier 3 tools (iron and pine) and have been using them ever since regardless of which life I have active?

Comment: Tools aren't mentioned at all in this question. You don't hve to change tools at all anyway. The question is just asking what the rate of experience gain is for skills that your current Life doesn't naturally have.

Comment: @Reafexus Oh I read it three more times cause I was confused why you were mentioning tools.. That is what you were making to do the comparison but one of the tools came out at a different quality, I got it. Ok, Still looking forward to what you find out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after some more experimenting I am pretty confident that experience overall is 50% (towards your character level) and Skill Experience is 75-80% for Lives that do not naturally have the Skill you are using. Interestingly enough crafting experience is not affected by the quality of the item you create. A Superior item nets you the same experience and skill experience as a normal one. EDIT: Combat skills below.

I will post the numbers I have later.

As a Blacksmith:
* "Good" Gold Pickaxe - 115 exp - 215 Smithing Exp
* "Good" Iron Sword - 25 exp - 71 Smithing Exp
* "Great" Iron Sword - 25 Exp - 71 Smithing Exp

As a Carpenter:
* Normal Gold Pickaxe - 57 Exp (50%) - 170 Smithing Exp (80%)
* "Great" Iron Sword - 12 Exp (50%) - 55 Smithing Exp (76%)

Combat Basic data. 33% Experience gain for a skill not naturally used by that Life.

As a Paladin:
* 3 hit combo on Pterodactyl - 15 Longsword Exp
* 2 Hits (one each on the sheep things in East Grassy Plains) - 6 exp

As a Mercenary:
* 3 Hit combo on Pterodactyl - 6 Longsword Exp (33%)
* 2 Hits (one each on the sheep things) - 2 exp (33%)

As a Blacksmith:
* 3 Hit combo on Angry Cactus - 6 Longsword Exp (33%)

Not sure how much more in depth I want to go. But I was very surprised how low the combat exp was for the wrong Life. And it looks like being a crafting job does not change the ratio.

Comment: Could you check the crafting where its the quantity that changes instead of the quality? I thought there was a boost there at the least. Like when you are making ingots instead of swords.

Comment: I think you lose out on exp but yea. I will see what I can do. I need to actually find trees anyway. A lot of the material recipes only give a handful of exp at a time. I will add what I can.

Comment: @James I added some more combat data. It is apparently a HUGE drop of 66% for at least the longsword skill. I am very surprised.